# Wordpress 500 Error on remote website, but works locally

Tags: database, wordpress, http-status-code-500

I encountered the dreaded wordpress 500 error but couldn't find a solution from other topics. Here is my situation:

- My site works fine locally, with the url localhost/zufic. It worked fine on my staging test.zufic.com as of this morning.
- I flushed my permalinks (on local) to fix some inconcistencies in page URLs, which worked
- After uploading the new database to my staging site (changing my URLs from local to remote, as usual), the CSS on my homepage is a mess, and all subpages give me 500 errors.

[Screenshots of the homepage between local & remote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7W7eQ.jpg)

I tried the following, to no avail:

- disabling all plugins
- flushing permalinks on the remote website
- checking my DB for a bad search/replace in my URLs, but all is fine
- reinstalling the core wordpress files
- deleting all remote FTP files and replacing them with the local WP folder
- uploading a backup of my remote DB
- Updating my PHP version

I also tried displaying error logs through wp-config but couldn't get them to show up for some reason.

I certainly messed up something, but what? Any tip for how to proceed and save my sanity?

---

UPDATE:
So I checked the logs, where this error shows up repeatedly:

```
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://test.zufic.com/
```

From what I understood, it comes from a faulty .htaccess? I reset it on the remote site (renamed the existing file, flushed the permalinks to generate a new htaccess) > I can see my subpages now, but the CSS is still messed up.

Here is my remote htaccess (=default WP file):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here is the error I see in WP_debug:

```
[16-Sep-2021 14:56:00 UTC] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home/zuficcomap/test/wp-includes/sodium_compat/src/Compat.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/zuficcomap/test/wp-includes/sodium_compat/autoload.php on line 45
[16-Sep-2021 14:56:00 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/zuficcomap/test/wp-includes/sodium_compat/src/Compat.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php7.0/lib/php') in /home/zuficcomap/test/wp-includes/sodium_compat/autoload.php on line 45
[17-Sep-2021 09:15:22 UTC] PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /home/zuficcomap/test/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 1098
```

The Compat.php file IS present at the specified location so I'm not sure why it can't be found?

Comment: Check the error logs on your webserver

Comment: Thanks for the tip , they're daily logs so I don't have those for today yet. I'll update tomorrow when I have them.

Comment: I checked the logs and updated my initial post. Any idea?

Comment: As you can see in the logs, you have some missing files. Check them or check if it's available for the webserver.

Comment: Thx, as mentionned in the post the file IS present on the server at the address specified, so I don't know why it can't find it...
I ended up reinstalling the whole website from scratch directly on the remote server and the problem is gone - I guess I'll just have to keep working without a local environment :/

Comment: If the file is present on the server, the problem is the file permissions. Check that the webserver has access to that file.

Comment: got it, I'll check that if it comes up again! thanks